# 2 multi sites with separate root pages

Tags: structure, multi-site

I have 2 sites within 1 Craft 3 installation, they are both the same language and generally have nothing to to with each other.

I would like both to have individual startpages at the URL "/".

- Is this possible?
- With 1 or 2 sections (structures in my case)?

Thanks,
Matthias

Comment: What do you mean by having individual start pages at "/", do you mean on two different domains?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean: 2 different domains showing 2 different sites being served from one Craft instance and both domains should have a startpage at /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new site in Settings > Sites > New Site
2. Make sure "This Site Has Its Own Base URL" is checked
3. Go to the "Entries" section, publish a page, and set the entry slug as `__home__`
4. Return to the Entries section, switch to Site 2 using the dropdown menu at the top of the screen
5. Publish a page and set the entry slug as `__home__`

Craft knows which site each page belongs to, so there will be no conflict between the slugs.

You can use any section you like to publish your homepages, as long as the Entry URI Format in the section's settings doesn't require a special syntax. Many people use a "Single"-type section or a "Structure"-type section with a URL setting of `{parent.uri}/{slug}`. Make sure the section is available to be used by Site 2 in the section settings.

Comment: Thanks kmgdev. I always thought about different sections for each site and how I would enable them for one of the sites only. But the trick is to keep them in the same site.... Thanks!

Comment: Additional info: It also works if you have 2 different sections which contain the startpages for the different sites. Craft is smart enough :-)